# Compiled folder and PIE.htc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a bit of a noob to ruby/ rails so please excuse me if this is a bit of a beginner question.

I need to make some modifications to an existing project, and so far everything is going well, but I can't seem to figure out how to modify the stylesheets info. In my public folder I have a file call PIE.htc and a folder called compiled. Also, in my app folder (why there?) I also have a stylesheets folder with what look like partials for a stylesheet... all seems very strange.

Any ideas how I can add new css information to this project? I really only need to add a few short lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running on Rails 3.1 with the new asset pipeline. If that is the case then you can edit the css files in ./app/assets/stylesheets and then compile using a rake task when it comes time for deployment. Here are a couple of links that will help:

[Asset Pipeline Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

[Asset Pipeline Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up that the project was using Scss (Sass). Actually a great way to make css code!